Trying to concatenate with variable value getting Undefined in Cypress
    cy.get('#name').type('Mani')

    var Name =cy.get('#name').text

    cy.log(Name)

    cy.log(Name+ 'Hello,  this practice page and share your knowledge')

I stored the name in the 'Name' variable and display it properly in cy.log(Name). But when I am trying to concatenate with variable(Name) it's getting unefined.
I want to be display like "John Hello...."

Please read the documentation at Variables and Aliases.
The standard way to handle variables in Cypress tests is via an alias. The syntax you need is cy.get(something).as('myVar')
In your example
cy.get('#name').type('Mani')

cy.get('#name').invoke('val').as('value')

cy.get('@value').then((value) => {
  cy.log(value + 'Hello')
})

// in an automated test, use should() to check the value

cy.get('@value').should('eq', 'Mani')


Try this
cy.get('#name')
  .invoke('val')
  .then((val) => {
    const msg = `${val} Hello ...`;
    cy.log(msg);
    console.log(val + ' Hello'); // if you must
    debugger; // use your cypress browser dev tools console to experiment
  })


Again, If  I am storing ${val} in another variable its showing error like var msg =  ${val}+'Hello'
cy.log(msg)

that wont work - see string interpolation - val+'Hello', should do, if you really don't want to use interpolation which wouldn't normally be recommended
